# Using environmentObject in watchOS

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos, swiftui, watchos-6

I am trying to use `environmentObject` in a watchOS6 app to bind my data model to my view.

I have created a simple, stand-alone Watch app in Xcode 11.

I created a new `DataModel` class

```
import Combine
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

final class DataModel: BindableObject {

    let didChange = PassthroughSubject<DataModel,Never>()

    var aString: String = "" {
        didSet {
            didChange.send(self)
        }
    }

}
```

In my `ContentView` struct I bind this class using `@EnvironmentObject` -

```
struct ContentView : View {

    @EnvironmentObject private var dataModel: DataModel

    var body: some View {
        Text($dataModel.aString.value)
    }
}
```

Finally, I attempt to inject an instance of the `DataModel` into the environment in the `HostingController` class -

```
class HostingController : WKHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var body: ContentView {
        return ContentView().environmentObject(DataModel())
    }
}
```

But, I get an error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '_ModifiedContent<ContentView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<DataModel?>>' to return type 'ContentView'
```

The error is because the `WKHostingController` is a generic that needs a concrete type - `WKHostingController<ContentView>` in this case.

A similar approach works perfectly with `UIHostingController` in an iOS app because `UIHostingController` isn't a generic class.

Is there some other way to inject the environment to a watchOS view?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to inject .environmentObject() in watchOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57559200/how-to-inject-environmentobject-in-watchos6)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can use type erasure, `AnyView` in the case of SwiftUI `View`.

I would refactor `WKHostingController` to return `AnyView`.

This seems to compile fine on my end.

```swift
class HostingController : WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        return AnyView(ContentView().environmentObject(DataModel()))
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I had tried `AnyView` but I hadn't used `AnyView(ContentView())`

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get the following error:
"Property 'body' with type 'AnyView' cannot override a property with type 'ContentView'"

Comment: Just got back to this after a few months, fresh eyes helps.  I still had ContentView in the Generic protocol declaration, changed to AnyView and works.

Comment: How do you get a child ContentView to access this in the latest WatchOS app templates? I have this working on my main ContentView, but when I route to a view with `NavigationLink` I can't figure out how that ContentView would have access to the same `@EnvironmentObject`

Comment: This is bad answer as `AnyView` is performance heavy. Long story short, put your data model inside content view. [Here's better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57560836/1162044.)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone like Brett (in the comments) who was getting

```
"Property 'body' with type 'AnyView' cannot override a property with type 'ContentView'"
```

I got the same error because I hadn't replaced the return value and wrapped the ContentView being returned.

ie. this is what my first attempt looked like.. notice the 
`WKHostingController<ContentView>`
that should be
`WKHostingController<AnyView>`

```
class HostingController : WKHostingController<ContentView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        return AnyView(ContentView().environmentObject(DataModel()))
    }
}
```

Comment: I had done that bit though, but I hadn't replaced ContentView in WKHostingController<ContentView> with AnyView, that worked for me. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Matteo's awesome answer,

If you want to use delegate then use like this:

```swift
class HostingController : WKHostingController<AnyView> {
    override var body: AnyView {
        var contentView = ContentView()
        contentView.environmentObject(DataModel())
        contentView.delegate = self
        let contentWrapperView = AnyView(contentView)
        return contentWrapperView
    }
}
```